How do i get the bash command below to stop echoing these bash alias not found errors?

I think these bash commands were created with the intention of increasing htops refresh interval, cant remember where i found them. However I have since figured out all that was needed to do to get it to refresh faster was to edit the /.config/htop/htoprc with nano and it worked out fine. However, the bash: alias not foud errors remain... How would I go about entirely removing those erros and scripts without just having the terminal only ignore them, but fully remove them? I dont know how to stop this echo in my terminal. As you can see in my screenshot, it sadly continues to do so even in a new terminal window, even after restart! I have run every debsums switch to see if there were any issues, they all came back finem except for a sysctl.conf (from procps package) though these are two different issues, I think the procps package is from my firewall rules, but I'm not sure about that... my rules for ufw are
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     DENY        Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                DENY        Anywhere (v6)


included are my screengrab of terminal.
here are the bash errors
bash: alias: -d: not found
bash: alias: 5: not found
bash: alias: -d: not found
bash: alias: 1: not found
bash: alias: -d: not found
bash: alias: 0.2: not found
bash: alias: -d: not found
bash: alias: 0.1: not found
bob@bob-ao533:~$

those were caused by one of these.
sudo echo "alias top="top -d 1"" >> ~/.bashrc

sudo echo "alias top="top -d 5"" >> ~/.bashrc

Then for the debsums issue it found, that was after running sudo debsums -as, though, other main switches of debsums including these -cs -ls and standard -s -as was the one who found that sysctl.conf (from procps package) though.

Your question is really hard to understand. Try using code formatting whenever possible (with backticks) and inserting correct spacing.

Not an answer to your question, but that sudo there makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. What's there in an echo that could not run as a normal user and requires superuser privileges? Your ~/.bashrc is writable by you, but if not due to some really unexpected circumstance then sudo wouldn't help because redirection happens earlier, still with your (not the superuser's) privileges.

And please don't post images of text.

You have a string-quoting problem.
You can't put double-quotes inside double-quotes because there is no difference between the start and end of a double-quotes pair. So for bash your command looks like this (quotes start with <<< and end with >>>):
echo <<<alias top=>>>top -d 5<<<>>>
which means the following is written to your .bashrc:
alias top=top -d 5
This is not what you intended and this is why you get the -d: not found error.
Instead use single-quotes inside double-quotes like this:
echo "alias top='top -d 5'"
Hope this helps a little
Edit: As other people noted here, there is no reason to run the echo with sudo to add lines to your own .bashrc file.
Also, it wouldn't actually write to the file with elevated privileges, because redirections happen before the command is executed, with the privileges of the shell you run in.
To actually write with elevated privileges, you have to do it like this:
echo "your line" | sudo tee -a your_file
Or run the whole line in an elevated shell like this:
sudo bash -c "echo 'your line' > your_file"

OP has more problems than just string quoting. e.g. sudo echo "alias top="top -d 1"" >> ~/.bashrc ...WTF? They don't have write permission on their own profile nor home dir? Or they are expecting this to modify the root profile? What has the firewall got to do with bash errors?

@symcbean, sudo wouldn't help to open ~/.bashrc as it's the shell that opens the file to redirect's sudo output. Using sudo doesn't make sense as echo doesn't need any superuser privilege.
